# Expected Value for Number of Consecutive Cards of the Same Suit

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Here is the setup.  Shuffle a deck of 52 cards so their order is random (i.e., determined by a uniformly distributed random variable).  Now flip through the cards and find the maximum number of consecutive cards with the same suit.  My question is: What is the expected value?

I don't know very much statistics, but I can't seem to find a straightforward way of getting to the answer because you're taking a max over a set of values.  Intuitively, it seems like the question may be easier to answer if you consider the deck only up to cyclic order (so you're allowed to get to the top and keep counting from the bottom) because then there are no "preferred" cards.  I'd be happy with an answer either way.

Preliminary testing with a deck of cards in my office indicates the answer is probably between 3 and 4.

Comment: To get an estimate, assume each card is independently uniform one of the $k$ suits and there are $N\gg 1$ cards total. Let $p=\frac 1 k=1-q$. Then the expected max run length $l$ is approximately solution to $qp^lkN=1$ which yields $l=\log_k N(k-1)\approx 3.64$.

Comment: In the original problem statement, if there are $c$ cards per suit, then expected number of runs of length at least $l$ is $$k\frac {\binom c l}{\binom N l}\frac {N-c}{N-l}N$$
which in your case is approx $2.14$ for $l=3$ and $0.45$ for $l=4$, so your answer is around $3.5$.

Comment: One can, of course, use brute force to compute the number (there are only around $10^{10}$ possibilities). But otherwise it is extremely hard to calculate precisely. If the cards were returned to the deck, this would be a lot easier but still pretty hard.

Comment: @zhora You don't even need to return cards to the deck (I assume this means i.i.d. draws) - it's enough for the deck to be very large for approximations to become very good. The interesting thing is that its not entirely clear (to me) exactly how long complete runs are correlated. OTOH, one eats up space, OTOH, it slant the remaining distribution making another run more likely compared to uniform.

Comment: @A.S., yes, approximate numbers are not hard to get as you wrote (I wrote about precise numbers). There are some problems though. The main asymptotic term is indeed $\log_k N$ and the next term is probably constant. But I am not convinced that this constant is $\log_{k}(k-1)$. And for numbers like $3.5$ the constant is quite important.

Comment: @zhora You might have meant exact rather than precise. In the i.i.d.case, the constant term oscillates around $\log_kN(k-1)+\gamma/\log k-\frac 1 2$ where the second term can be derived from Poisson Heuristic as above (yielding Gumbel's distribution for $L_{max}$) and $-1/2$ is due to discretization. How did you get $\approx 10^{10}$ possibilities for fixed proportions? I'm getting $\approx\binom {52}{13}\binom {39}{13}\binom{26}{13}/4!\approx 2e27$.

Comment: @A.S., probably I goofed.

Comment: @A.S. What was your reasoning to arrive at the equation $qp^lkN = 1$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My DP Python program gives 149116192125870533506434119 / 44703948137907327366031200
exactly, which is approximately 3.335638088740207.